# Terminal Server - Licensing Issue

Tags: terminal, windows-server-2008-r2

I had to recently demote a domain controller and re-promote it, and in this process I renamed the domain completely. Now, because I had to rush this job I overlooked a few things, for instance my primary concern is that the DC is used as a terminal server. Licensing was installed fine before but now because of the domain name change, under the "remote desktop session host configuration" tool it is still showing the old licensing server e.g. SRV01.contoso.local but the new server is SRV01.contosobusiness.local therefore putting me in a grace period, do I have to reinstall the licenses? Is there a way to modify the server name to reflect the new changes?

I'm using windows server 2008 R2.

Comment: Never mind guys I figured it out. Cheers!

Comment: You should delete this question or post a answer to your question and mark it accepted. If you do not it will keep popping up to the front page as an unanswered question.